# How can $\{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\}_{n=0}^\infty$ to be strictly decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I needed to determine whether the sequence $\left\lbrace\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right\rbrace_{n=0}^\infty$ is increasing, decreasing, or neither. It is obvious that this sequence is oscillating. However, I also know that if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} < 1$, then the sequence is strictly decreasing. This creates a contradiction because
$\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}} = \frac{(-1)(-1)^nn^2}{(-1)^n(n+1)^2}=-(\frac{n}{n+1})^2$
Since $(\frac{n}{n+1})^2 > 0$, thus, $-(\frac{n}{n+1})^2 <0 < 1$, which means the sequence is strictly decreasing.
I'm guessing this is because the test only works on monotonic sequences, though I don't see why that would be the case.

Comment: $\{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ should be right.           Secondly, $a_n $ should be positive , for saying it is decreasing by $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \lt 1 $

Answer (score 2):

No, a **positive** sequence with $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ is decreasing; a **negative** sequence with $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ is actually **increasing**: if $a_n<0$ and $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$, multiplying the inequality by $a_n$ reverses it, and you find that $a_{n+1}>a_n$. And of course if the signs alternate, the ratio of consecutive terms will always be negative.

Comment: sir kindly help us https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785307/on-the-nonnegative-integer-solutions-that-satisfy-sum-x-i-leq-n

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} <0$ does not imply  that  $a_{n+1} <a_n$. You cannot multiply inequalities by negative numbers without reversing the inequality sign.

Comment: Well, you *can* multiply inequalities by negative numbers, but the direction flips.